# publish app for Android Market and iOS appstore with android:versionCode & Bundle Version > 1?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

OK first I appologize for the long title, but trying to make the question as clear as possible.  Here is what I want to do, and want to know if anyone has tried this before and if so if they had any issues.

I want to publish an app to both the Android Market and iOS appstore with a version above 1.0 (for instance 1.4).  In other words the android:versionCode & Bundle Version would not start at 1.0 for the first time I am submitting this app to either store.  I need the versioning for some server services, does anyone know if this would be an issue for either market?

I haven't seen anything that says it would be an issue, but just figured I would ask to see if anyone has come across this before.

Comment: anyone know about Apple appstore?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are talking about "Version Name". Version code is an integer value, and hence, setting it as "1.4" is invalid.

Hence, assuming you are talking about "Version Name", the answer is it is perfectly OK to start with "1.4". This will not be an issue at all. Android market uses "Version Code" to detect an update and notify your users. The only purpose of "Version Name" is for display.

Here is the android documentation regarding versioning:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: oh thanks, no sorry meant version code > 1 so I guess 2 or 3 for the first publishing.  I already read that article but didn't see anywhere were it said you could start the version code at higher than 1 for the starting apk.  I actually care more about if it is legal to do it for the appstore.

Comment: I have published to android market without any issues with version code that was not in sequence. I am not sure about Apple's app store, as I am in the process of learning iOS, and don't have any apps yet for IOS devices.

Comment: alright thanks, will upvote that for the android answer, thanks a lot.